# rails keeping model validation errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, validation

here is a frequent scenario: user has a dashboard in order to show some related information to the user. also, use can do some actions in his dashboard. according to abstraction, each of these actions, has its own controller and they are not all in the dashboard controller. for example, in order to update some information about user, you have `user controller` and not the `dashboard controller`. `dashboard controller` is only for rendering some information.
ok? now you have a form in your dashboard, posting the inputs to an arbitrary controller and we want to render the results(success message if succeeded and pre-populated form with errors if failed) in the dashboard. if we use `redirect_to` in the controller, we lose the validation errors and pre-population. if we use `render`, there will be uninstantiated variables in the dashboard template and we run into some errors.
what are the tricks to handle this?
**P.S:** there were some similiar questions but the answers were using `render` but it leads to  the mentioned problem and doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it via ajax and remove/add appropriate html elements dependent on success/failure.

Or you could have

```
if @user.save?
  redirect_to dashboard_path
else
  @my_instance_variable = InstanceVariable.first
  render "dashboard"
end
```

Comment: instantiating unrelated variables in this controller breaks abstraction. doesn't it?

Comment: Yes but for what you want your options are either do that or use ajax.  If you're using rails 4 you could put them in a concern that's included

Comment: Or just fetch them in a private controller method that's called in a before_filter